# Android schedule a task 4 times per hour

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, android-calendar

I need to run a task to collect some data 4 times per hour. I guess best way to do it is using AlarmManager. I managed to get following code working and it runs for every 10 sec.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval = 10000;

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But I want my task to run 4 times per hour. Exactly at XX.00, XX.15, XX.30, XX.45. This is to generate some data graphs.

Can somebody tell me how to archive this? Should I use Calendar class? I could not find any clear method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
put interval=15*60*1000 and instead of System.currentTimeMillis() put the milliseconds of XX:00.If you want this time from user then You can use using TimePicker dialog to do so.